# Adding unlink in PDO query

Tags: php, pdo, unlink

I was looking for some guidance on to add an unlink line to the below update function, everything i try doesn't process and im quite stuck..i want to delete an image from a folder and set the database value to NULL (value updating works)

The code i've tried works on an href button if done seperately but i can't manage to add it to the update function.

assistance would be greatly appreciated,

**code tried:** `unlink('receipts/'.$expenses->image);`

**PHP Function**

```
// Remove backup file
function deleteBackup()

{

     $query = "UPDATE " . $this->table_name . " SET image = NULL WHERE id = ?";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

    if($result = $stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And where does that code get `$expenses` from?

Comment: What is `$expenses->image`? Where is `$expenses` defined? Can't you just do a select to get `image` first, update your database and then unlink it with the value you got from the select?

Comment: Do you use a debugger? Why not? If you did, you wouldn't have to ask questions like this.

Comment: Please give more code... we more interested here`$expenses->image`

Comment: Can people please stop up voting questions that don't contain nearly enough information to be answered? Seen this on _many_ questions today.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson $expenses is the php file where all the functions are stored, and image is the database column the value is stored in i.e. thisisanimage.jpg. i will try to change it to a SELECT query and grab the file name to update to NULL and then unlink?

Comment: What does this have to do with the database query?

Comment: @miken32 because i want to update the database and then unlink the image file from the directory in the same process, so i wrote the question in that sense. apologies if there was misleading information.

Comment: I'm sorry, but _"$expenses is the php file where all the functions are stored, and image is the database column the value is stored"_ didn't make it more clear and doesn't actually make much sense. You need to show us _all_ the relevant code or we won't know what's what.